# when check box is checked value price doesn't convert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my code i want to change price when check box is checked or unchecked, when i checked another checkbox then all checkbox is going remove but doesn't remove checkbox price its removing checkbox but doesn't remove price. means its should be set to zero again. help me please.

```
<div class="price" id="amount">₹0</div>

<div class="check">
<label id="somede-div" class="first2" for="check-2"><input id="check-2" 
class="first" name="save2" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹749<span id="somede-element">IBPS PO 2017 Mocks (20 Prelims + 10 
Mains)</span></label>
<label id="some-div" class="first0" for="check-0"><input id="check-0" 
class="first" name="save" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹1999<span id="some-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching 
Course</span></label>
<label id="somed-div" class="first1" for="check-1"><input id="check-1" 
 class="first" name="save1" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹2999<span id="somed-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching Course + 
30 Mock Tests</span></label>
<label id="somedef-div" class="first3" for="check-3"><input id="check-3" 
class="first" name="save3" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3499<span id="somedef-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive</span></label>
<label id="somedeff-div" class="first4" for="check-4"><input id="check-4" 
class="first" name="save4" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3999<span id="somedeff-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive + 30 Mock Tests</span></label>
<div class="mask"></div>
<div class="helping">Please select any one box</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var changePrice = function changePrice(amt, state) {
            var curPrice = $('.price').text();
            curPrice = curPrice.substring(1, curPrice.length);
            if (state == true) {
                curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) + parseInt(amt);
            } else {
                curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) - parseInt(amt);
            }
            //alert(curPrice);
            window.curAmount = curPrice;
            curPrice = '₹' + curPrice;
            $('.price').text(curPrice);

            //alert(curAmount);

        }

        $(function() {
            $('#check-0').on('change', function() {
                $(".helping").css("display", "none");
                var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-0"]').text();
                itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
                changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-1').is(':checked'));
                $(".first").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                /* if ($('#check-0').filter(':checked').length >= 1) {
             changePrice(parseInt(curAmount) + parseInt(itemPrice));
    $('input.first').not(this).prop('checked', false);
           }*/
                //changePrice(parseInt(itemPrice) * parseInt(curAmount));

            });
            $('#check-1').on('change', function() {
                $(".helping").css("display", "none");
                var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-1"]').text();
                itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
                changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-1').is(':checked'));
                $(".first").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                //alert(itemPrice);
            });
            $('#check-2').on('change', function() {
                $(".helping").css("display", "none");
                var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-2"]').text();
                itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
                changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-2').is(':checked'));
                $(".first").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                //alert(itemPrice);
            });
            $('#check-3').on('change', function() {
                $(".helping").css("display", "none");
                var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-3"]').text();
                itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
                changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-3').is(':checked'));
                $(".first").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                //alert(itemPrice);
            });

            $('#check-4').on('change', function() {
                $(".helping").css("display", "none");
                var itemPrice = $('label[for="check-4"]').text();
                itemPrice = itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length);
                changePrice(itemPrice, $('#check-4').is(':checked'));
                $(".first").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                //alert(itemPrice);
            });

        });
```

Comment: DRY your code man :( looks awful

Comment: above is html and below is js... simple..

Comment: bhai, seriously it looks awful.

Answer (score 1):

Dry your code, select the elements relative to your clicked input,right now you are unchecking the previous checked input so you don't need the function because you don't have a sum you have a single checkbox checked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first').on('change', function() {
    $(".helping").css("display", "none");
    var itemPrice = $(this).parent().clone().find('*').remove().end().text(); //this will remove all the spans from your label and allow you to get the price
    $('.price').text($(this).is(':checked') ? itemPrice : '₹0');
    $(".first").not(this).prop("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes


  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price" id="amount">₹0</div>

<div class="check">
  <label id="somede-div" class="first2" for="check-2">
  <input id="check-2" class="first" name="save2" type="checkbox" />
<span class="checkbox"></span>₹749
<span id="somede-element">
IBPS PO 2017 Mocks (20 Prelims + 10 Mains)</span>
</label>
  <label id="some-div" class="first0" for="check-0">
 <input id="check-0" class="first" name="save" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹1999<span id="some-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching 
Course</span></label>
  <label id="somed-div" class="first1" for="check-1"><input id="check-1" 
 class="first" name="save1" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹2999<span id="somed-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching Course + 
30 Mock Tests</span></label>
  <label id="somedef-div" class="first3" for="check-3"><input id="check-3" 
class="first" name="save3" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3499<span id="somedef-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive</span></label>
  <label id="somedeff-div" class="first4" for="check-4"><input id="check-4" 
class="first" name="save4" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3999<span id="somedeff-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive + 30 Mock Tests</span></label>
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="helping">Please select any one box</div>
</div>
```

if you want multiple selected options then do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var changePrice = function changePrice(amt, state) {
    var curPrice = $('.price').text();
    curPrice = curPrice.substring(1, curPrice.length);
    if (state == true) {
      curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) + parseInt(amt);
    } else {
      curPrice = parseInt(curPrice) - parseInt(amt);
    }
    //alert(curPrice);
    window.curAmount = curPrice;
    curPrice = '₹' + curPrice;
    $('.price').text(curPrice);

    //alert(curAmount);

  }

  $('.first').on('change', function() {
    $(".helping").css("display", "none");
    var itemPrice = $(this).parent().clone().find('*').remove().end().text(); //this will remove all the spans from your label and allow you to get the price
     
    itemPrice = itemPrice.trim().substring(1, itemPrice.length);
    changePrice(itemPrice, $(this).is(':checked'));

  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price" id="amount">₹0</div>

<div class="check">
  <label id="somede-div" class="first2" for="check-2">
  <input id="check-2" class="first" name="save2" type="checkbox" />
<span class="checkbox"></span>₹749
<span id="somede-element">
IBPS PO 2017 Mocks (20 Prelims + 10 Mains)</span>
</label>
  <label id="some-div" class="first0" for="check-0">
 <input id="check-0" class="first" name="save" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹1999<span id="some-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching 
Course</span></label>
  <label id="somed-div" class="first1" for="check-1"><input id="check-1" 
 class="first" name="save1" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹2999<span id="somed-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching Course + 
30 Mock Tests</span></label>
  <label id="somedef-div" class="first3" for="check-3"><input id="check-3" 
class="first" name="save3" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3499<span id="somedef-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive</span></label>
  <label id="somedeff-div" class="first4" for="check-4"><input id="check-4" 
class="first" name="save4" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3999<span id="somedeff-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive + 30 Mock Tests</span></label>
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="helping">Please select any one box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: should it not be `prop"checked", false)` and not `attr("checked", false)`?

Comment: this is for checkbox remove if another checkbox click.

Comment: @GauravMehra yes,is that a problem?

Comment: but i want to remove checkbox, when another clicked. and your code not working.

Comment: so you will have only one checkbox clicked at any time yes?

Comment: Thank You so much man.... workes fine... what was my mistake in my codes

Comment: @GauravMehra you had many mistakes, the major one you didn't realize that you don't need to add or subtract because you only have a single checked element

Comment: ok, i understood. when i have multi check then + and - require. thank you man, hats off.....

Comment: @GauravMehra for multi check then yes you need to add and subtract see the second part of my answer(show code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier you don't need `changePrice` function for that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/87d2pq78/#&togetherjs=Rq4U3xgPcp)

```js
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        $(".helping").css("display", "none");
        var itemPrice = $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
        $('.price').text($(this).is(':checked') ? '₹'+itemPrice.substring(1, itemPrice.length) : '₹0');
        $(".first").not(this).prop("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price" id="amount">₹0</div>

<div class="check">
    <label id="somede-div" class="first2" for="check-2"><input id="check-2" 
class="first" name="save2" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹749<span id="somede-element">IBPS PO 2017 Mocks (20 Prelims + 10 
Mains)</span></label><br/>
    <label id="some-div" class="first0" for="check-0">
    <input id="check-0" class="first" name="save" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="checkbox"></span>
    ₹1999
    <span id="some-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching Course</span></label><br/>
    <label id="somed-div" class="first1" for="check-1"><input id="check-1" 
 class="first" name="save1" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹2999<span id="somed-element">IBPS PO 2017 Online Coaching Course + 
30 Mock Tests</span></label><br/>
<label id="somedef-div" class="first3" for="check-3"><input id="check-3" 
class="first" name="save3" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3499<span id="somedef-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive</span></label><br/>
<label id="somedeff-div" class="first4" for="check-4"><input id="check-4" 
class="first" name="save4" type="checkbox" /><span class="checkbox">
</span>₹3999<span id="somedeff-element" style="right: 9px;">IBPS PO 2017 
Online and Pendrive + 30 Mock Tests</span></label><br/>
    <div class="mask"></div>
<div class="helping">Please select any one box</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you forgot the unchecked state, with by adding it will make your answer similar to mine